# Array "breaks" when resizing

Tags: c++, arrays

Well, I have a class which is supposed to be a container for quadratic polynomials (which is a template and I'm using floats there, but that shouldn't matter much). I made it using a dynamic array, and I was supposed to overload + and - operators... Not a problem, eh? Well, it seemed all nice and dandy until I actually run it.

```
listf listf::operator+(listf rhs)
{
    listf newlist;
    for(int i = 0; i < elementcount; ++i)
        newlist.add(array[i]);
    for(int j = 0; j < rhs.elementcount; ++j)
        newlist.add(rhs.array[j]);
    std::cout<<newlist;
    return newlist;
}
```

Nothing much. Should do its job correctly, right? That cout is just to check if it works. But it does not.
Should do something like this, right?
With one list consisting of:

```
X^2+5x+52.4
2X^2+7x-12
```

and the second one having just X^2+2X+1, it should make a list and display:

```
X^2+5x+52.4
2X^2+7x-12
X^2+2X+1
```

Buuuut no, it comes to this:

```
-1.5584e+038X^2-1.5584e+038x-1.5584e+038
-1.5584e+038X^2-1.5584e+038x-1.5584e+038
-1.5584e+038X^2-1.5584e+038x-1.5584e+038
```

I've been battling with it for quite some time and have not found why it would do that.

Code for adding new polynomials is still quite simple:

```
void listf::add(polynomial<float> plnm)
{
    if(array == NULL)
    {
        ++elementcount;
        array = new polynomial<float>[elementcount];
        array[0] = plnm;
    }
    else
    {
        array = resize(array, elementcount+1, elementcount);
        array[elementcount++] = plnm;
    }
}
```

And resize is a private function in this class:

```
polynomial<float>* listf::resize(polynomial<float>* arr, int newSize, int oldSize)
{
    polynomial<float>* newArr = new polynomial<float>[newSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < oldSize; ++i)
    {
        newArr[i] = arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;
    return newArr;
}
```

If we're making a smaller array (for deleting objects), I just put oldSize equal to newSize (I know it's a bad practice and confusing for others, but I was just testing things :( )

I'm out of ideas. Adding new elements to an object seems working, but when I want to add two objects it breaks, prints elements that are not correct and then crashes with CodeLite reporting something like "ntdll!LdrVerifyImageMatchesChecksumEx" in Call Stack. Even better, when I tested it right now, it displayed correct values, but still crashed at return.

Comment: Just use an `std::vector<ploynomial<float> >` then it will take care of this for you.

Comment: Can you post enough of the code for us to build and test this? Please [read this](http://www.sscce.org/) for a description of good example code.

Comment: @user3556899 - As pointed out, you're attempting to reinvent the wheel with this dynamic array.  `std::vector` has `push_back()` to add an item to the end of the vector, has `resize()` to change the vector's size, etc.

Comment: Eh, can't use std::vector, that's one problem. Second, while I could provide the entire code, it's quite a lot including the class and the template and more of a problem is it's not in English and wouldn't be easy to read.

Comment: Any reason you can't use `std::vector`?

Comment: `Eh, can't use std::vector, that's one problem` That's like saying "I am trying to build a chair, but must make the hammer and nails myself". Think of the chair as the "polynomial solver", your home-made array as "the home-made hammer and nails", and the hammer and nails you would buy in the hardware store "std::vector".

Comment: @user3556899 - The issue is that your dynamic array is so far off, that it is better that you create the dynamic array class separately, and ask questions about that implementation, and not clutter the question with polynomial solving code. Once you have that working, then you can use this self-contained class like std::vector within your polynomial code. To create a dynamic array correctly requires much more focus than trying to shoehorn code into a polynomial solver.

Comment: @Mgetz - it's a container of polynomials. It must be something that has to be done for a school project or something and it was explicitly said that I can't use std::vector. PaulMcKenzie - I'll rewrite that probably few more times until I get it working... But asking never hurts, right?

Answer (score 1):

Forget the home-made dynamic array and use vector.  Whenever you go into the realm of classes and memory management, it isn't as trivial as coding up a few new[] and delete[] calls.  It can stop you dead in your tracks in the development of your program.

```
#include <vector>
//...
typedef std::vector<polynomial<float> > PolynomialFloatArray;
//...
class listf
{
   PolynomialFloatArray array;
   //...
   void add(const polynomial<float>& plnm);
   //...
   PolynomialFloatArray& resize(PolynomialFloatArray& arr, int newSize)
};
//...
void listf::add(const polynomial<float>& plnm)
{
   array.push_back(plnm);
}

PolynomialFloatArray& listf::resize(PolynomialFloatArray& arr, int newSize)
{
   arr.resize(newSize);
   return arr;
}
```

There in a nutshell is all of that code you wrote, reduced down to 2 or 3 lines.

Comment: Eh, the problem is I'm not supposed to use that... If I could, I wouldn't ask, just use vector.

Comment: @user3556899 - `Eh, the problem is I'm not supposed to use that` So what is the goal of your application? Is it to implement a dynamic array? If so, why clutter things with polynomial solving? Just create a dynamic array class, irrespective of what application it will be used for. If however the goal is to create an app that solves polynomials, then why is it being impeded by a non-working dynamic array class? Just use std::vector.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments on the question point out, you would probably be better off using `std::vector` for this, as it has `push_back()` to add stuff to the end, and automatically resizes itself to do so, though you can force it to resize with `resize()`.